# Change fullCalendar title date format for day view

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I would like to change the date format which is displayed above the calendar.

https://codesandbox.io/s/2z6wp2jozn?file=/src/DemoApp.jsx

When you select day view, you can see `December 21, 2020`.
I want to change the format of the date and display `Monday, 21.12`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `views` prop

```
<FullCalendar
   views={{
     day: {
         titleFormat: { month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', weekday: 'long' },
      },
    }}
/>
```